# Mosaic by Albrecht Dürer

Tags: logical-deduction, visual, grid-deduction, no-computers, minesweeper

This is a visual puzzle (known as "mosaic" or "fill-a-pix") with the same rules as MineSweeper:

- The grid is to be filled with colored and white tessera. Choose whatever color you like for the colored ones.
- The number in each cell indicates how many colored tessera there are in a block of 9 cells around the number - including the numbered cell itself.
- There is absolutely no guessing involved. The color of the tessera must be deduced by the numbers given in the grid.
- If you fill all the cells correctly, you are rewarded with a picture by [Albrecht Dürer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albrecht_D%C3%BCrer).
- Since the rules are so simple, solving it by a computer algorithm is trivial. **No programming allowed!**

The rules are easy. The size of this puzzle does make it difficult, though. A tiny error can carry forward through many cells until you notice it.

**Hint 1:** It becomes easier to solve if you find two numbers next to each other that have a difference of 3:

[image]

There must be 8 colored tessera and only one white one in the green box. If you put the white one to the right, the red box must have 6 colored tessera in order to add up to 8, but there must be no more than five. That means that the one white tessera of the green box must also be in the red box, adding up to 5 colored ones. Ergo the remaining tessera in the red box but outside of the green box must be white. Also the remaining tessera in the green box but outside of the red box must all be colored because 5 (in the red box) + 3 = 8.

**Hint 2:** You can apply the same principle to blocks of cells that are partially solved:

[image]

There must be 5 colored tessera in the red box and 4 of them are already solved. Ergo the red box must contain one more colored tessera.
There must be 4 colored tessera in the green box and 3 of them are already solved. The green box is also missing one colored tessera, and since it must be inside the red box, the remaining tessera in the green box but outside the red one must be white.

---

Since we are supposed to avoid social contacts in the current Corona outbreak, I wanted to give you a fun and relaxing pastime that can be puzzled on a computer or with pen and paper.

[Microsoft Excel file](http://www.filedropper.com/duerer): The unresolved cells are pale red. Fill the mosaic with white and any color of your liking.

[PDF file for printing](http://www.filedropper.com/duererprint): You probably need to print it on 2 pages. Choose a pencil or sharpie of your liking. Mark the white tessera with a small dot and fill the colored tessera with your pen. Make sure you can still read the numbers in the colored cells.

[CSV file](http://www.filedropper.com/duerermosaic) for those who'd like to format the grid themselves or use other applications than Microsoft Excel.

The puzzle in a CSV format is below:

```
;3;;4;3;;;6;;;;;;6;5;;;;;5;;;4;;;5;;;5;;3;;;;2;0;;2;;;4;;;;3;;;4;5;;4;2;1;;1;;;4;4;;;1;3;;5;;;;3;3;;;;;;;2;;;;;;0;;;;;0;;1;;;;;;;;0;;;1;;4;4;;;3;;;2;
;4;6;;;;7;9;;5;;;9;;;8;7;;;;;7;6;5;5;7;;;;6;4;;;4;;2;2;;;5;5;;4;;;;;;;5;;;;;4;;;;;;4;;;;7;6;4;;;;;;5;;5;;;;;0;0;;;2;;1;;2;;;;;0;;;1;2;1;;1;;5;;6;5;5;;5;;;
2;;5;7;5;4;5;;9;;;7;9;;9;;7;7;8;7;;;;5;;;;6;6;4;4;;4;;;;;;2;3;;;4;2;;3;5;4;;2;;1;;3;;6;6;;;8;;4;;;6;7;6;4;;3;3;4;;5;;5;;4;1;0;1;3;;4;2;3;;;1;1;;1;;;0;;3;;;;3;;5;4;3;3;4;4;6;;
;;5;;;4;;;;7;;6;;;;8;8;;8;7;6;;;5;5;7;8;6;6;;;4;4;3;;;5;5;;3;3;;1;;3;;6;;4;2;2;;;;;7;;8;;;9;;;;4;7;;;;4;;3;;3;3;;;;3;;4;5;5;;;;3;;1;0;;;1;0;;3;;;;;;3;2;2;1;;3;;5;4;
1;;;8;5;3;3;;8;7;5;;7;;;;;8;;6;5;7;6;;;;6;;;;;5;;;3;4;;;;;;3;;3;5;5;;5;;4;4;5;;5;;;8;;;;8;8;;2;;;;;6;;;4;;;4;;4;;;;5;6;6;;5;5;;2;1;;;3;2;1;2;4;6;;4;;;1;;0;1;3;5;5;;;
;4;;;;4;;;7;;;5;;8;8;;;9;;7;;;;;6;;;;5;;6;;5;;4;;7;;5;;;2;3;;6;5;5;5;6;;5;5;;;7;8;;;;;;;;;;;8;;;5;6;;;;;;3;;;;4;;4;;4;4;3;;;;2;;;;2;;;5;4;4;;;;;3;5;5;4;;3;
;;4;7;6;;;4;;;4;5;6;;;8;9;;7;;;;5;7;7;;5;;4;6;6;7;5;;5;6;6;;;3;3;2;;6;7;4;4;;;;6;;;;5;;;;3;;;;;;;;9;7;6;3;3;2;;;6;6;;4;;;4;5;;4;;3;;4;;5;;;5;;;4;4;;;5;;3;;3;4;;5;4;5;;
;5;;7;;;3;;;8;5;;;9;;8;8;8;;8;6;6;;;8;8;7;7;6;7;6;6;;6;6;5;;3;5;4;;;3;;;;;;;4;4;;3;3;3;;3;;;4;4;4;;3;;5;;7;5;;;1;;;5;;;7;5;;;;4;4;;3;3;;;4;5;;5;5;5;5;4;3;;;3;;3;;5;;4;;;4;
;;5;;7;;4;4;;;;;;8;9;;8;;8;;;6;6;6;7;8;7;6;;7;6;5;5;;6;4;;;5;;4;1;3;3;;2;2;;2;2;2;3;;3;;2;2;;4;;;4;5;3;3;;;;3;2;;2;3;4;;;6;7;6;;;5;;;;4;3;;;4;;;;7;;5;4;;6;4;3;2;;;5;5;;5;;;
;4;5;;7;8;;;;7;;3;5;;;;7;;8;7;7;;6;;;;7;;5;;4;;;;5;;5;;;5;;;3;2;1;1;2;2;;;;0;;;3;;;5;6;6;7;;6;;3;3;;6;;;;;2;3;5;;5;;;2;3;;4;;;;;5;4;;;;;4;5;5;;;4;3;3;;5;6;;4;4;;6;4;
;;;5;7;;6;;6;5;;;6;8;;7;;6;;;6;5;6;5;;7;;6;6;;;;2;2;4;;;;7;5;4;;4;;1;;;1;0;0;0;0;2;;5;4;6;;;7;;;;3;3;3;;;3;4;1;;0;;;4;;1;;;3;;4;;;;;7;;5;;4;;;;3;;;3;;;4;5;6;6;;;5;;;
;5;6;6;7;;6;;;;5;;;;9;7;;5;7;6;;5;;;7;;7;7;;;;0;;0;;3;;;6;;3;;;3;0;;0;;0;0;0;;2;;6;;7;;6;;7;7;;3;2;;4;6;;;1;1;;1;;;;1;1;1;;;;5;;;5;;;6;;4;5;;;5;5;;2;;2;;;4;;;3;4;;;
;;5;;6;;6;8;;;;5;;;;;;7;;;6;;8;;7;;6;6;6;5;2;;;;;;;2;;;3;4;3;;1;0;;;;1;;4;4;4;;;;;;;8;8;6;;;;4;;5;3;;;;;;;1;;;;3;;6;;4;;;7;5;;;5;;6;5;4;;;3;3;;2;2;1;;;5;;3;;
;;;6;;6;5;8;;9;;;;7;8;;7;8;;;;;8;;;6;;;5;;3;;;1;0;;0;0;1;;2;;;4;;;2;;2;4;;;6;6;;;7;7;;8;;9;;;2;;4;4;6;;;;2;1;2;;;3;;;;5;;6;;;4;7;;;1;3;4;;;7;;5;;;3;;3;;;5;4;3;3;;
;6;;;;;;;8;;6;;;6;;;6;;;8;;;8;;7;6;6;6;;;4;3;;;;0;0;;;;2;1;;4;;5;;2;3;;6;;7;6;;5;7;;;9;9;;;;;3;3;;6;5;7;5;;;1;2;;;3;;4;4;4;;4;5;3;;;4;;2;3;;;;;4;;;5;;4;;;7;7;;4;3;
6;8;;;;5;5;5;;;;3;;6;8;;;;8;;6;;;7;;5;;;6;5;4;;2;;1;;0;;;2;;0;;;;;;5;;6;6;7;;8;7;6;;;9;;;;;6;4;;;;;6;7;;4;;2;;5;;4;;;5;5;;4;;;;;;2;;;;4;;6;;5;3;;;4;4;;;7;6;;4;
;7;;8;8;;;;7;7;7;;;6;9;8;;;7;8;;7;;;;;6;;7;;;;;;1;;;1;4;;;2;3;4;;5;;4;;5;5;;;;7;7;8;;9;;;;;;;;;;4;;;;;5;3;3;4;4;;3;;5;;6;5;4;4;5;6;;;2;;4;4;;;;;5;;3;4;3;;5;;;;3;
;;;;;8;8;6;;7;8;5;4;;;;9;;8;7;6;6;;;7;6;6;;8;;4;3;3;;;;3;;6;;4;3;;5;;;;6;;4;;5;;8;8;;;;;;9;9;9;6;6;;3;3;3;;;;4;;;;4;4;3;;3;;4;;;;;;;1;1;;5;;;6;;;;2;;;5;4;;;6;4;;3;
;3;2;;5;7;8;;;;9;;;5;;;;6;7;;;5;;8;7;;7;;8;;;3;;5;5;;;;;7;;;5;;6;6;;;5;5;;4;6;8;8;;;;8;7;7;;;6;6;3;2;3;3;;;7;6;6;5;4;;5;;;0;2;2;;;4;;;5;;;;4;;;5;4;;2;2;2;3;5;5;6;4;5;;;;
2;3;;;;6;;7;;8;;4;;4;7;8;;;6;6;6;;5;;7;;;;8;;;;6;;8;;;;8;7;;6;;;4;;;7;;;;5;;;;9;;9;;;5;5;;7;;3;;;3;6;;;5;4;;4;;;2;;0;;1;2;4;4;6;3;;;;0;;3;;5;4;;1;1;3;;6;5;;5;;6;;4;
;;;5;6;6;5;;6;;;4;3;5;;;6;4;;;7;;;;7;;8;8;;5;;4;;;7;;8;;;8;9;;;;4;;;7;8;9;;;8;9;9;;8;7;5;;4;;;;5;4;1;2;;5;7;;;5;;;3;3;2;2;1;2;;;;4;;3;6;;3;1;1;;;;;2;2;2;;3;5;5;;;6;5;;3;
4;6;;8;;;;6;6;7;4;;;;6;;;6;7;;8;;6;7;8;8;;;7;;5;6;;8;;;;9;9;9;;;;1;2;4;7;;;8;;;7;7;8;;7;;;;;;6;7;;;;;;4;7;5;7;4;;2;2;1;0;1;2;;1;;4;;;;;;;1;;2;1;2;3;;;3;;;7;;8;7;;5;;2;
;;;;;;8;8;;;;;3;5;;;8;;9;;;;7;7;8;7;;6;;6;6;;;;;9;;8;8;;6;4;;1;;;7;;8;;8;;;7;8;9;;;;7;;;;7;6;;;2;2;;;;;4;;;;1;;3;;2;;1;;4;5;;;;;;;3;;;2;1;2;2;;4;;5;6;;4;;;;
;;6;5;;6;7;;;;7;7;;;;7;;;8;;8;8;6;6;;;6;;8;;7;7;7;;6;7;7;;;;4;4;4;;;5;7;7;7;;;;6;;8;9;7;;;;;;9;9;;6;3;;1;;;5;5;;;2;;2;4;4;4;2;1;;;;;;;6;;;;2;;2;;1;;3;;;4;;3;3;;;7;;
2;;;;5;;4;5;;8;7;;;;2;;;9;;;;8;6;;;7;7;;;6;;;;;;6;;7;;;3;;4;;;6;;;;;7;5;;7;9;;;;8;;9;9;;7;7;5;4;;1;;2;;;5;;;2;3;;;;;;;2;;3;5;3;;;3;2;3;;4;3;2;;;;;;3;3;;5;6;7;;
;4;;;;;2;;5;;;9;;;3;5;7;;8;;;;;;;;7;;7;6;5;;7;;7;5;6;6;;;2;;4;;;;8;;;8;;;7;;;;;8;7;8;;9;;6;;5;;2;;3;;;;;2;4;3;;;6;;2;;;0;3;3;6;3;6;;;1;;;;4;4;3;3;3;;;;4;;;5;5;;
3;;2;5;4;4;;4;;;6;9;8;;;;;;8;;;;;7;7;7;;6;;;;;;;;;;;4;;1;;;5;8;9;;;;8;;;7;;4;;;8;;;8;;8;;4;4;;3;;;;5;3;3;1;;4;;;;;;1;;;;;5;;6;5;5;;;4;;5;4;2;2;;;7;7;6;6;;3;;;
3;;2;;;5;;;;4;;;;;;6;9;;8;8;7;8;;;;;6;8;7;;7;;9;;9;;;4;;;0;;4;;;6;;;5;;;7;6;3;2;;;;;;;;;;4;;4;;1;;3;;;;;3;;;8;6;4;;3;;;2;;;4;6;;6;;;;4;;2;;;6;;6;4;;;5;;;;
;;;5;;;;;;;6;;7;;5;6;8;8;7;7;7;8;7;7;;7;6;;;;;7;8;;9;;7;;;0;;2;4;;;5;;;;5;8;;;4;3;;;;7;7;9;;9;6;;4;;6;;2;;3;;3;;3;;5;;;;2;;;1;2;;;;;;6;;5;;2;2;;4;6;7;5;;4;6;;;;5;3;
1;;;;7;4;3;;3;4;6;7;;;;5;;7;7;8;;8;8;7;6;;6;;;6;5;;7;;8;8;;2;0;;;;;;4;;;;;4;7;7;6;;;5;7;;7;;9;;;;;;;;4;2;3;4;6;;6;4;3;;;;1;;2;;;;;;6;;5;;4;;;3;;4;5;5;;;4;4;5;;;6;;2;
;;6;;;;4;3;5;5;;7;;;5;;;;;;;;8;7;6;;;7;9;7;;5;6;8;;;;;0;;3;;;;;;3;;;5;7;9;8;;;4;5;;6;;6;7;;;7;;9;;;;2;4;;6;;4;2;;;0;;2;;1;;;4;3;;4;3;3;;;5;;;;;6;;;3;5;6;7;7;;4;;
2;;8;6;3;;;4;;;;7;8;6;;;6;;;9;8;;;6;;4;5;7;8;8;;;7;7;7;;;;;4;6;7;7;7;5;4;3;;4;;6;8;8;;2;;4;;;6;6;6;6;;;8;;;4;;;4;5;7;5;;;1;;0;;;;2;;5;5;;3;4;;;;6;8;7;6;4;;;2;3;4;6;6;6;6;;;3;
;5;8;;;;5;5;;4;;8;;;;5;;;;8;;;7;7;;;5;;;8;;7;;;6;4;2;1;;6;;;;7;5;;4;6;5;;6;7;8;5;3;;2;5;5;6;4;5;;7;;;8;;;1;;;;6;5;;;;2;;1;;;4;;;4;3;;4;3;3;3;;;6;;3;;4;;4;;6;6;;6;7;;;
2;;;7;4;4;;5;;5;8;8;6;;;6;9;;;;8;8;;5;4;6;;;;;;6;;;;;1;;;7;8;;7;6;4;;4;;;4;5;5;;6;;2;3;4;5;;;4;;;5;;5;5;5;;1;;4;;;;3;;;0;1;;3;;;5;;4;4;5;;;;;6;5;;2;;;;;7;;7;;6;;6;3;
1;;4;;;;4;;2;4;;7;;;;;;;7;7;7;;;7;;;6;8;8;;7;5;6;5;4;;;0;3;;;;;3;2;;;4;;5;5;;5;;6;;;3;;;3;;1;;;;;6;;;;1;;;6;;;2;1;1;;;;4;5;4;;2;3;;5;4;5;5;;;2;;2;;;;;;6;;;7;;;
;;;;2;;;;3;;8;6;;;5;;;9;8;;7;;6;6;5;;;;8;8;7;;;4;;;;;4;5;6;4;3;1;2;;1;;2;4;4;5;5;6;;7;;4;;4;4;4;;;4;5;;5;5;;;2;2;;5;;;;2;3;;3;;3;;;6;;5;;6;;;4;;;;;;;;5;;7;;7;;;5;;
4;;4;;1;2;;2;;6;;5;;4;;9;8;;7;;5;6;6;;;5;;;8;8;7;5;;;3;0;;3;5;5;;;;0;1;1;1;;;;;5;;4;;5;;;2;4;;6;;6;6;7;;;;7;;;1;4;;;;5;;3;;;5;;5;;;5;;3;4;;5;;3;;5;6;;6;;4;4;6;;7;;7;;;
;7;;3;;;;1;;7;;;;;8;;8;;;7;;;4;;;;6;7;;8;6;;;5;;;;;4;;;1;;2;;;4;4;5;;5;;4;;3;3;3;;;;3;6;;;6;7;5;4;5;6;;3;1;;;;;;;4;5;5;;;;3;;;;;;4;;4;;;3;;;;6;;;;6;6;;6;;4;
;;5;3;2;3;3;;;8;6;;;;;;;7;6;5;;;;5;;4;;8;8;;;;;;4;1;0;;4;6;;;4;;4;;5;6;;;;;;4;3;2;3;3;4;;3;;3;;4;;;4;;;;;;;;6;;;6;4;;5;;;3;2;;;;;2;;3;;6;7;6;;6;7;;8;;6;;;7;;8;6;
2;;;;2;;;;5;;5;5;5;8;8;9;;;;6;;4;4;;5;4;;;;7;;6;;;;;;;3;5;6;;;;6;;5;;;;;3;;5;;5;5;;;3;2;2;;;;;2;2;;;8;;;;;;6;4;5;4;;;;3;;2;;4;3;4;;;;5;;;4;;;;8;;;5;;5;;7;8;5;
;;;3;2;3;2;5;;;;;5;8;;8;;8;;;;;;;5;4;;;;;;7;6;;;;;;;6;;8;8;;;3;;;;;3;3;;;;;;5;6;6;5;3;;;;0;;;4;;;6;;;3;;6;;;;;;;3;;;;;1;2;4;4;;4;;6;7;;;6;6;6;;;7;;;6;;5;
3;;4;;2;2;1;4;6;6;;3;6;;9;8;8;;8;;;4;5;6;;6;;5;6;5;6;;6;5;;1;2;;;5;;8;;;;4;;6;;6;;;;;;;;;;5;;;4;2;2;;3;3;;;;6;4;1;2;;5;;;2;;;2;;1;;2;2;;;;3;;3;;;;5;;;6;;6;6;;;6;;;;
4;;;2;;2;;4;7;;;;;;9;;8;6;6;4;4;4;;;7;8;9;;;;7;6;7;;2;;;3;4;4;;8;7;;3;4;6;;;6;;;;5;;;4;5;7;8;;5;;3;;;;;;2;4;;;;;;;;3;;2;;;;;2;3;;;;1;;3;;;;;6;;6;;5;5;6;8;8;6;;7;;
5;5;;;2;;;5;;;5;;;5;;;;;6;3;2;3;;;7;8;8;;9;7;;;;;;3;5;;;;;;;5;4;;;5;;5;;9;;8;;4;2;;;;;;5;;3;2;;;3;2;;5;6;;1;0;;;2;2;;4;;3;4;;;4;;;1;3;3;;;;5;;3;;;7;;;8;8;7;7;;;
;5;;2;;3;5;;7;;4;4;6;;7;;7;7;6;;;5;;7;;;;8;7;7;6;;;;;4;;3;;;;;;6;6;;;4;;;5;8;;9;;4;;2;;3;;;;3;;0;1;;2;;;;6;4;;;2;3;4;;;2;2;;4;;5;;;3;;3;;4;3;5;6;5;3;;6;7;6;6;6;7;6;;;;
;5;3;2;;3;6;;;;2;;;5;;8;;;;6;5;6;;;7;8;6;;5;;5;;;2;3;;;1;;;0;2;;;8;8;;2;;2;;;8;;5;3;0;0;;0;;;;;1;0;0;2;2;;;;7;7;;1;;4;;4;2;;2;2;4;;4;4;;;2;;6;4;;;7;;;5;;6;;6;6;6;;5;;4;
2;5;;;4;;;6;6;;;;5;;;8;8;6;;;6;;;6;6;8;;;;;3;2;0;2;;;;;;;2;4;;7;7;5;3;;;2;;;;8;;3;;;;;0;1;;;1;0;;;;1;0;2;;;4;;;6;8;6;;;3;3;;;6;6;;;3;5;;;4;;5;7;;7;;6;5;5;;5;;;5;4;
3;;;3;;;;;;;;;4;4;;;9;7;4;;;;7;;;6;;7;;;3;;;;;;0;0;;;;4;;;;3;;;5;;5;6;7;;5;;;;;0;;;;1;;;;1;;2;;4;;6;;;3;;7;;5;;;;;6;8;8;6;4;;;;7;6;4;;;;7;;6;;5;;4;;4;;3;
;;4;;4;2;5;;;;4;6;;5;6;6;9;7;;4;6;8;;;6;6;;7;8;;3;;;0;0;;0;;2;;5;;;4;;1;;;;;6;6;;;;7;4;;;;;;1;1;0;0;;0;1;2;4;;7;;6;3;3;;;5;;;;5;;6;;;4;4;;6;7;;;;4;;5;;6;;5;;;;;6;6;;
;;3;2;3;;;4;3;1;3;;8;7;;7;;8;;;;;;6;;;;;7;;3;;;;;0;;3;;;;4;;5;;3;2;;;8;7;;;6;7;8;;;;;;;;0;;;0;;1;;5;;;;7;5;3;2;2;3;3;;;4;;;;6;;4;3;;;;;;;5;4;;;4;4;;;;7;;;;
;7;;;4;4;5;;;;5;7;;8;;;;;;;8;;6;;;9;7;;;5;2;2;;2;;;;4;;;7;;7;;;4;;;;;8;7;;6;;;;;1;;;0;;0;;1;;1;2;3;;;6;8;7;;4;;0;;;5;5;;4;4;;;5;;;4;;6;;6;;;;7;;4;3;4;6;;;7;;;
5;7;6;6;;;6;6;;4;5;5;5;6;;;7;6;7;7;7;;;5;5;8;7;;7;;;2;;4;;4;;;5;6;;8;;;9;;;;;;;7;6;;5;5;4;;2;;0;;;;;1;1;;1;;;3;;7;;7;;3;;1;3;5;5;5;3;3;3;4;5;;3;3;5;;4;5;4;5;;5;;5;;6;;6;;;8;;
3;;;7;4;;;5;;;7;5;;;;;;;;7;;7;;;;;7;;;;3;;;;;;;;6;;;9;8;;;;;8;;9;;;7;;;;5;;;3;;;1;;;;3;;3;;2;4;5;6;;;;;2;0;;;;5;4;3;;;;;4;;4;;4;5;5;;4;;;7;7;7;;;;7;;5;
;;6;5;4;5;;;3;;;;5;;6;;;8;;7;6;;;;;;6;8;;8;;5;5;;;6;;7;;8;;8;8;;8;;8;;;7;;;;6;;5;;6;5;5;;3;2;;2;;2;2;3;;;;;;8;;;5;3;2;;4;4;5;5;;;2;3;;;;4;;3;;3;3;;4;;7;7;7;;;;;7;;
;3;;;5;5;;;;;;;8;;7;;;;7;7;6;;6;;7;;5;;8;9;;;;;;;;9;;6;6;;;5;6;7;;;5;;;;6;6;6;;5;;;;;;2;;1;1;3;;5;;7;;;;7;8;7;5;;;3;;4;6;;;;4;;;;;5;6;6;;;;4;4;4;6;6;;;7;6;6;;;
;;4;;6;7;6;;0;;;7;;8;;5;5;;8;;7;;;6;;5;6;;8;8;9;;9;;;9;9;;;4;;5;5;4;;;6;4;;;6;6;7;7;;;2;;4;;5;5;;3;;;3;5;;7;;8;;;8;9;;;4;4;4;;;;;;5;;;2;;;;8;7;6;;7;;;5;;7;7;;7;;8;7;;
4;;;4;;;;;;;;7;7;9;7;5;5;6;;;7;;4;4;4;;;;;8;;;;;;;;;4;3;3;;2;1;;6;;6;;6;5;6;;;5;;3;;;;5;;6;6;;5;;7;;;5;5;;6;6;;;;;;4;2;3;;;2;;2;3;;;;7;;;7;;6;;5;5;5;6;;7;;;9;;;
6;;;5;7;;4;;;6;;5;;7;;;7;;7;7;7;7;6;5;;5;;;8;7;;7;;;9;;9;;;4;4;;2;;;;6;6;;;5;6;5;;;3;4;2;2;4;6;;;7;7;;8;7;7;5;;;;;6;7;7;6;5;4;;3;;2;2;;2;2;2;3;3;;;6;;;;6;6;6;;5;;7;;8;;;7;;
;6;7;;;;;;;;7;;5;;6;5;;7;;;6;6;6;6;;4;;8;;;7;;;;;;;;;;4;;;2;1;3;;;5;;;5;3;3;4;4;5;;4;;;;7;7;7;;7;;7;5;;1;1;;;;;;;;3;;;;1;;3;;;;4;;;6;7;6;;;;7;;;4;5;6;7;6;7;;5;
2;5;;;;;3;;;9;;6;;;;6;;;6;;6;;8;;;5;;7;;;;7;;;6;7;;;2;3;;;4;;2;;5;;3;3;4;;;3;3;;5;;6;4;3;3;;;7;6;;5;;;6;3;2;3;;6;5;5;6;;;;2;;1;4;;;5;4;3;;5;;5;5;;;6;6;6;;4;;6;;;6;6;;
;;4;;;5;2;3;;8;;7;8;8;;7;6;;7;8;;7;;;6;;7;;;8;;8;;;;7;5;4;;2;2;4;5;5;3;3;;3;3;;3;;;;3;;3;5;;2;1;;3;5;;7;5;;5;;;6;4;;5;;;;;7;;;;2;2;;;4;4;;5;5;;;;5;;;6;;;5;;4;;;6;;5;;
;;;;4;4;;;6;;7;8;9;8;8;8;;7;6;;6;;6;7;6;7;;8;9;7;7;7;;;6;7;7;6;5;3;;;;;;2;2;1;1;1;;3;;;2;4;;;;3;;;3;5;;7;;4;3;4;5;6;;;4;7;6;6;6;8;9;;;5;;3;;3;;;4;;;5;5;;5;4;4;;5;6;;;5;7;6;;;;
;6;4;4;3;2;;;6;6;;7;;;8;;;;6;;;5;4;;5;7;6;8;;;8;;7;6;7;8;8;;;4;2;;;;;;3;3;3;3;3;;2;3;;4;;;4;;;;4;;;6;5;5;3;4;4;7;;;;;5;;7;;8;8;9;;;;;3;;;;3;;3;4;4;;4;4;4;5;7;6;;6;;7;;5;3;
;;6;5;;1;3;6;;6;6;7;;5;;;6;;5;;;;;;5;7;5;;6;7;7;;;;7;;;;;;;;1;;;;;;5;;;3;2;2;;6;6;7;7;;;8;;;3;3;;;;;;;;;4;3;6;;8;;;7;8;9;9;;;;;4;2;1;1;2;3;;3;;;3;;6;;;6;;5;;;;
;7;;5;3;1;4;6;;6;6;;5;4;;6;;5;5;;;;;;7;;6;6;;5;6;7;;7;;;;6;3;3;4;5;3;4;;;9;9;;;6;;;;5;;;;9;;;9;7;;;;1;;;;3;4;;;;;6;7;8;;4;;;;;9;;;5;5;;4;;;1;;0;;1;;2;;4;6;5;;6;8;5;3;
;;8;;;;;;8;6;6;5;;4;5;5;6;6;6;7;;7;;;7;;7;;3;4;5;;9;;8;;9;;5;;;;;;5;8;;9;;;8;7;7;7;;9;;8;8;7;7;7;;4;1;1;;4;;;;;4;4;5;5;8;8;;5;;;;7;9;;8;;;;6;;;5;;2;;;;0;0;;3;;;4;;5;;3;
;8;;;2;4;;7;7;6;6;;;4;5;5;5;;6;7;6;6;6;;5;;;;;;;8;9;9;;;8;;6;7;;;;;;;8;;6;;6;;8;;;;6;;6;;4;;5;;;1;1;;6;;;3;;4;;7;;;6;;;1;;7;8;;8;;7;;;;6;;5;;;;;1;;;;1;3;;;4;;;
;9;6;;;;8;8;;;6;6;5;;5;5;5;5;;;7;7;;;;5;;8;;;;9;;9;;;7;8;;;;;8;;7;;;;;3;;;5;5;5;;4;;;;;5;;;1;1;;;6;6;5;;;5;;;;6;;1;1;;;;;;7;8;;9;;;6;;;7;;6;;4;;;4;;3;1;2;1;;;
5;;5;2;2;;7;;6;;;;;;5;;5;5;6;5;;7;7;5;;5;;8;;;9;8;;;;;6;;;;9;;;;;;3;;;;0;1;2;;2;;;5;;4;3;5;;5;;1;;;;;6;;7;;8;;;;2;;3;5;5;;3;;6;;;9;;;7;6;;;;9;;;5;;;5;5;;;;1;0;
4;;3;2;4;;7;;;6;6;6;;6;;;5;;;5;6;;7;;4;5;;;;8;;7;;8;8;8;;;;;;;;;;2;;;0;;;;;0;2;;;;;4;3;5;6;;;3;3;;;;;7;;;7;6;;2;3;;5;;;4;2;4;6;;7;;8;9;8;;;9;9;;;;;;6;;6;;5;;;;
;;;;6;6;;;6;;6;6;6;;;5;;;;;5;6;6;5;;5;7;;8;7;7;;6;7;8;;7;;8;;;4;2;;2;;;;2;3;;;2;;;;8;8;5;2;;3;;4;;;;8;9;8;8;;;;;3;2;;5;;;6;5;4;;;7;7;;;7;8;;;;8;;9;;;;7;;7;8;;;6;;;
;4;;;;5;;5;;6;6;;6;;5;6;5;6;;6;;6;7;6;;5;6;6;7;7;6;6;;6;;;;;8;9;;3;;2;;;3;;;;;5;;;;;8;;3;2;;;2;;;5;7;7;;8;8;;5;4;2;2;;;6;;6;6;5;4;3;5;;6;;5;6;;4;;;;9;;;7;;;6;;8;;;;8;;
;;6;;;;;7;6;;6;7;;;;7;6;6;;6;;;;6;7;;;6;;;;;6;6;6;;6;;7;;7;5;4;5;;;;;8;;;8;8;9;;;;6;;2;3;;2;;2;;;;7;;;;4;2;;;6;;;5;;;4;3;;;;;6;;;;;5;7;8;;6;;;;7;9;;;9;;8;;6;
5;;;8;5;;;8;7;6;;6;7;;7;;6;;4;5;;6;6;6;;;;;;6;;;6;7;7;;;;;7;6;;7;;7;7;;;8;;8;;;7;;;;4;;4;4;4;2;2;;;6;;6;5;4;2;;1;;;;6;6;5;6;4;3;3;4;7;6;6;;;;4;6;7;9;9;;;;;4;6;8;;;;9;9;9;;
;;9;;7;6;;7;;6;;6;7;6;7;5;;4;5;6;;6;;6;5;;;;;;;;;;;;;8;;5;;7;;9;;;8;;;;;9;;5;;5;;;4;;4;;;;5;7;;;5;4;;;1;;5;7;;6;6;5;;;;3;;8;;;;;;;;;;7;5;4;;4;;;;9;8;;;;;6;
4;;;9;;;;;6;6;6;5;;6;;5;6;5;;;6;6;;;5;5;;6;6;8;;;6;;;;7;8;;;4;;7;;;;;;;8;;;7;;;3;3;;3;4;6;;7;;7;8;8;7;5;;2;;2;5;;7;;;;5;4;2;2;;7;;;;;;8;;;8;8;;;4;;5;;6;8;;;8;;;;;
;;;8;9;7;5;4;5;6;5;;5;6;6;6;;;7;;;;4;5;5;4;4;;;6;;;;5;5;5;;;;;;6;;;7;6;;;;6;7;7;;;;6;;;5;;7;;7;7;;8;7;6;;;3;;3;;;;4;4;3;;;;;6;7;;6;;;8;7;;8;8;;4;;2;;;;;8;;;;7;;;;
;;7;;;;6;5;5;;6;6;;6;;6;;6;;;;5;5;;5;;;6;6;;5;6;5;5;5;6;6;5;;7;8;;;7;;7;;8;;5;5;4;;;;;5;5;;;7;;4;4;5;6;6;;4;3;;4;5;4;;5;4;;2;2;;;5;8;7;6;5;;6;7;;7;7;7;6;4;;3;3;4;6;;;;6;;6;;6;;
2;3;;;8;8;;;6;5;5;;;7;6;6;;;;6;7;;6;5;;5;;6;;;5;;;4;6;6;5;;5;;;;;;6;6;6;5;;;;;;7;;8;;;4;5;;4;;;6;;5;3;3;;6;6;;;;4;4;;;2;;5;;;;6;;5;4;5;6;;;;;4;3;;;5;7;9;;6;;6;;6;;;
;5;7;6;7;;9;8;;4;;6;8;7;6;5;6;6;6;6;;7;8;;6;5;;7;8;;;;4;;6;;5;5;;8;;;;;;;6;;;5;;;5;;;7;;;3;4;3;;;;6;;3;1;3;5;7;7;5;5;;;4;3;;3;;5;7;6;6;;;4;3;5;6;6;6;;6;;4;4;5;7;8;;;;5;;6;5;4;2;
;;7;6;6;5;8;8;7;;4;;;;7;;5;5;;5;5;;;7;7;;5;;;7;5;;;6;6;5;4;;7;;;6;4;;;3;3;4;;;;5;6;7;7;;3;;2;;4;;;8;7;5;;1;;;;6;5;6;;4;2;1;3;;7;7;7;5;5;6;5;;;5;5;7;;7;;4;4;;;7;9;;;4;;;7;5;4;;
;;5;5;6;5;6;;7;;;;4;5;;5;;4;5;;5;6;7;7;6;6;6;7;8;7;;;5;;5;;;;;;6;5;2;2;2;3;;4;;7;8;;6;;;;;;;;;;7;8;;;;;5;7;;;;6;6;5;3;;3;5;6;6;5;;4;;4;;;;5;7;8;;5;3;3;4;;;7;7;5;5;;6;5;4;2;;
;6;;;;4;;5;;9;;6;;;4;4;4;4;5;5;;6;;7;6;6;6;7;7;5;5;6;6;;4;3;3;6;7;;;;3;;;1;;;;;;;;;4;;3;;5;;;6;7;;5;3;2;4;;6;;3;5;5;6;4;;;;6;;7;;5;;5;4;;;4;5;;;;;2;3;;5;;;8;;7;;7;5;4;;;
4;6;;4;3;;3;;;;;7;5;4;;4;;;6;5;;6;6;;5;7;;8;;;;5;;7;;;;;6;;2;;1;;;1;;1;1;;;5;;;1;0;;5;;;;;;;;;2;4;5;;4;4;5;;;4;5;;;6;6;5;5;;;;4;4;4;4;;6;7;6;;;;;;7;;;6;8;7;;5;;4;3;
4;;5;4;2;5;4;;4;;;;7;5;;3;4;5;6;5;5;;6;7;;7;6;;;;;6;;5;;;4;;3;1;1;;2;;1;;;1;;1;2;3;;;;;1;3;;7;;;;4;;2;4;;;3;;4;;3;3;2;;;7;;;;5;5;6;6;;;3;3;;;;;;;;6;;8;6;;7;;8;7;5;5;5;;
3;;3;;;;;4;;2;4;5;;7;;5;4;5;;5;4;5;6;7;;;;6;5;;;4;6;;3;2;;3;1;;;;;0;;;;0;1;2;2;3;;;;2;1;;;;;7;5;;1;;;3;4;;;4;4;4;;3;;;7;6;4;5;;;6;;;5;;3;4;5;5;;4;6;6;;8;6;;5;;9;;7;;6;;;
;5;;;2;;5;4;4;;4;;;;8;;5;5;4;;3;;6;7;;7;;5;;5;;;6;;3;1;;;;1;2;1;;;;;1;;1;1;1;;;5;;;;0;;;;6;;1;1;;;;;3;4;2;2;;;;6;7;;5;;;;6;5;5;6;;5;3;5;;;4;;;8;9;;7;5;;7;8;7;;6;6;5;;
4;;;;2;2;;3;;3;;;;7;8;8;8;;;4;4;4;6;;8;;;5;6;4;6;;;4;;;;3;4;;1;;1;;;;;;1;1;;2;;4;;3;;0;;3;5;4;2;;;;3;4;4;3;;;2;;5;6;7;;6;6;6;6;5;4;;4;;7;;;5;5;4;3;;7;9;8;;6;;;7;7;8;7;;;6;;
3;4;3;;3;3;4;;3;;6;8;;7;;8;;;7;;4;;;;;7;8;;5;;6;;;;;;;;;;;;;;2;1;;1;1;0;;;2;;5;;3;;;;4;;2;;;;;;;;2;;2;2;5;7;7;6;5;;;6;5;;2;4;5;6;5;;5;5;;4;5;7;;;;8;;6;;;;7;7;;;5;
;;;;;;;;;7;;9;;7;;8;9;;8;7;;;3;4;;6;;5;5;4;;;7;;6;;6;;3;;1;;;;1;;0;;;;1;2;2;;4;6;;6;;;;1;1;1;3;3;5;4;;2;2;3;;;6;7;;4;;;;6;4;3;;4;;6;6;;;5;;5;6;;9;8;;7;6;;;7;6;;;6;;;
;;;;;4;;8;;;;;6;;7;;7;;8;;;6;;;5;;4;4;;5;;;5;;6;4;;3;;1;1;2;;;;1;0;0;;0;0;1;1;;;;8;;6;;2;1;;3;;;5;3;2;;;5;;5;7;7;;;;6;6;;;4;5;;5;;6;6;;;;;;;;;;6;5;;6;;;;;;8;;
;5;3;;;;7;;;6;;6;;4;;;;;6;;9;;;;;;2;3;2;;4;6;;;;3;2;2;3;;;0;;;;0;;;0;;;1;;;3;;;4;;2;3;4;;3;4;4;5;;3;3;5;5;5;6;;5;;;;;;3;;4;6;7;6;5;6;;;4;;8;9;9;9;;6;5;4;;6;7;;6;7;;8;;
4;;;;6;;;;6;;4;;4;;3;;;;4;6;8;9;9;;;;;;0;;;;5;;7;;;;4;3;;0;;0;0;;;;;2;;;;;;;;;;;;5;5;;4;;;2;2;;4;;;;;;5;6;8;7;;;1;;;7;;;;;;;;9;8;8;7;7;5;;3;;;;7;8;;;;6;
;;7;8;7;8;;6;5;;6;5;;2;2;2;;;2;4;6;7;8;9;;;;5;3;2;2;;;7;7;5;;2;;4;;1;0;;;2;;3;2;2;;0;;;1;0;;;1;3;5;;4;3;3;3;3;;;;;;6;;;6;;;;;;;;;6;;;;3;2;;6;;;;;;7;4;;;;;;8;9;;;8;;
;8;9;8;;5;;;6;;4;;;5;;2;;2;;;3;;;;8;9;;;6;;;4;;;8;;3;1;;2;;1;;0;1;3;;3;;;1;;;1;0;;;1;2;;4;;3;;3;3;1;2;1;;;5;;;;;;;5;3;3;4;;5;;6;7;6;;3;5;;9;8;;7;6;5;2;;;;8;;;;;;7;4;
;7;6;;5;;;3;;5;5;;;3;;;4;;5;5;;;6;;6;;8;;9;;7;7;7;;;;;;1;;;2;;3;;3;;3;2;;;;;2;2;1;;;3;2;;;;;4;4;3;;3;;;;8;8;;7;7;6;;;;6;;;5;;8;5;;4;;9;8;;6;7;7;5;;3;6;;9;;;;9;8;;;
;;5;4;;1;;;5;4;3;;4;5;4;;4;;7;6;;;6;7;;;;6;7;8;;;9;;;6;;0;1;2;;2;;3;;;;3;;;3;4;5;;;;5;3;4;2;4;4;4;3;;;;1;;2;;7;8;;6;;;5;2;;5;;;5;;7;;;;6;8;8;;;7;;;;4;;;8;8;9;;;7;;;;
4;;;2;;2;3;2;;4;;;3;4;5;6;5;;;7;;;;6;;6;6;;5;;8;;;;;;4;2;2;;;4;5;;;3;4;4;;3;;;4;;;4;6;;;2;;;;3;3;;3;;3;;6;;;;7;;;;3;5;6;;6;7;7;;4;4;6;8;;;5;;;;;6;;;7;7;8;;;6;4;3;3;;
3;4;4;;3;1;;;3;2;;4;6;;5;;4;4;5;;;6;6;6;;5;;4;5;;6;;;9;9;8;;;2;;4;5;;;3;;;;;3;4;;4;4;5;;5;;5;;4;4;3;3;2;;;;;3;;;6;6;;;6;4;4;5;;;;7;6;5;;6;8;8;7;5;5;6;7;;6;;7;7;;;;;6;3;;;5;;
4;;;2;3;3;4;;2;2;;3;4;;6;5;4;3;;;6;6;;6;6;;5;;6;;;6;;8;9;;8;7;;3;4;;5;3;2;2;1;;4;4;;;;4;;;5;5;;4;;;4;;;;;4;4;3;4;5;;;;;7;6;;5;5;;6;;;;5;8;9;;;;5;6;;;;8;;;7;8;8;6;;;;6;;6;
;;4;;5;4;4;3;3;3;3;4;5;5;;;4;4;4;4;;6;;5;;;;5;6;5;4;4;5;;;8;9;7;5;;6;;5;4;;2;;;;;5;6;7;;5;6;;7;4;;;;;4;;4;;;3;2;3;;6;;9;9;8;7;6;5;5;5;;;;5;;8;8;;5;4;;;7;7;;;;;;;;;;;;7;8;;
;;5;;5;;5;;4;4;3;;3;4;4;4;;4;;5;4;;5;5;4;3;;4;4;4;;5;5;;;7;;;;6;6;5;4;;2;;3;5;5;;4;5;6;5;6;;;6;;4;;;4;;5;;4;;2;3;4;6;6;8;8;9;8;;5;4;5;4;5;;5;;8;8;;4;4;5;;7;7;;;;8;8;;;;;4;6;7;;;;
;4;4;5;6;4;3;4;6;;3;;5;;;;;5;;5;6;7;5;;3;;3;3;;;;4;;5;5;;;8;8;;;7;;5;;3;;6;;;5;5;6;5;6;;6;5;;;;2;;4;4;;;;1;4;;;;;8;8;;;;5;5;5;;6;;8;;7;;;5;7;8;;;;8;;7;;;;5;5;;7;7;;;6;
;7;5;4;4;;;;4;4;;5;;4;;4;4;3;4;;5;;;6;;2;2;2;2;3;;;5;;6;7;;;9;;7;6;6;5;4;;6;8;8;7;6;;6;6;;5;;3;3;;;4;4;;2;2;;2;;;;;8;;6;;6;5;;5;;;4;;8;;;6;;4;6;;8;;;;9;;;;4;5;6;6;;8;;9;;;
;5;4;;5;;5;;5;;3;;6;;;5;7;;4;;;6;5;5;4;4;4;;4;4;5;5;;6;;6;;6;8;7;;;8;;;7;;8;;;;7;;7;;5;5;;4;;3;5;4;3;;3;;4;6;;;;;7;6;;6;;6;6;5;5;6;8;9;;;4;4;;;;;;9;;;5;4;;;7;7;;8;9;;7;5;;
4;;5;;5;7;6;6;3;4;4;6;;4;;4;4;;4;;4;4;;4;;;5;5;4;4;;;6;;5;5;;5;;;8;8;;;8;;9;8;;;;9;9;9;;;;7;;5;6;;;;;;5;;8;9;;7;;;;5;5;;5;5;6;;;8;;8;;4;;;;9;9;9;;6;;;;;7;8;;8;8;;5;;3;2;
;;3;;;6;;8;;4;3;5;;4;;5;5;;;4;4;4;3;;4;;6;;6;5;6;5;6;4;;;4;4;5;;;7;;8;;;;;;8;;;;9;;;8;;;;8;8;;7;7;8;;;9;8;6;;5;6;;6;5;;4;;6;8;;8;;6;5;5;;9;;9;;;5;;3;;;;;9;;;6;4;3;;4;;
;4;;3;;5;;5;4;;5;5;5;4;;4;3;4;;;3;;4;;4;;6;6;5;6;6;;;4;4;;;;5;6;;6;;7;;;;8;8;;8;;9;9;;8;;9;;;;;9;;;9;;;;8;6;4;;;;;6;;4;;7;;9;;7;6;;;8;9;;;;5;4;4;;5;;7;8;;;;4;3;4;5;6;;
;;;2;;3;;6;6;;;5;;;;4;4;;;3;;3;4;;;;;;8;;6;3;;4;;6;;7;6;5;5;5;5;;;8;7;7;;;;;;8;8;;8;;;;;7;;;;9;;;;;6;;;;;;;;;7;;;;;;;7;;;7;5;4;;;;;;;7;7;;;;;;5;6;7;;;
0;1;;;2;;;;;3;;3;;;3;;;2;;;2;;;;2;;;4;;5;;2;;;;;5;;;4;;;;3;4;;4;;;4;;4;5;;;6;;6;6;6;;;;5;;;;;6;5;5;;5;;;6;5;;;;;6;;6;;5;;;5;;;;1;2;4;;;5;6;5;4;2;2;;;;;;4;;
```

Comment: Generally we require puzzles here to be self-contained -- part of the purpose of this site is to be an archive of puzzles, and any offsite resources have the potential to break. So I've added the puzzle into the question itself - hope you don't mind!

Comment: @Deusovi Thank you, I haven't thought about that.

Comment: Technically that's Semi-colon Separated Variables not Comma Separated Variables :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor Technically you're correct, but Excel didn't complain, so I guess it doesn't matter ;)

Comment: Can I just check, the top row of the CSV has some numbers > 6 in it, does that imply that there is effectively a "blank" row above the top row listed?

Comment: @Vicky sorry for the confusion. The csv included in the question was not displayed correctly. I changed the formating and now all lines are fully displayed.

Comment: Having spent quite a while working manually on the original version, I didn't feel like doing it all again when the data was updated! So I wrote a script to solve it. It can't resolve the edges properly (which is almost certainly a bug in the script rather than the data) but I can tell enough from the middle to work out which Durer image it is. Would you like me to post this as an answer, or not given that I worked it out with a computer?

Comment: On further debugging / experimentation I don't think the right hand edge issues are a bug in my script. I can't solve those bits by hand either.

Comment: @Vicky Hmm, I'll have a look at my script tomorrow, but I tested it with several smaller images. Right now it's getting late where I live, so please give me a few hours

Comment: @Vicky I tested the csv included in the question again and my program can solve it (which is not surprising since it created the csv in the first place). But at least we ruled out a copy paste error. I still need time to solve this one manually, but I'll post my results as soon as I have them.

Comment: Ah, I've got it now. When I read the CSV in I was effectively creating a blank column down the right hand side. If I strip that off it becomes solvable. Thanks!

Comment: out of curiosity, how did you generate this puzzle? great job tho! :D

Comment: @athin First I wrote a program that solves the puzzle. To create a new one, it puts the correct number in every single cell, then iterates through all cells and checks if the puzzle is still solvable after removing the number.

Comment: @Vicky Since no-one else has posted an answer till now, feel free to post yours, even if it's solved by a computer.

Comment: Elmy, why the rush? I for one was 75% of the way through solving this the long way round. I have given HOURS of time to this (more fool me) - and now the green checkmark is given to an answer that solved it *by computer*?? Considering your original no-computers plea I have to confess I'm a bit miffed... Please don't set rules if you are going to ignore them!

Comment: @Stiv Sorry, after so many days I had the feeling that no-one was still working on this. I removed the checkmark to give you a fair chance. Please don't be disconcerted, your comment actually means a lot to me and I don't want to dissappoint you.

Comment: On Puzzling we often have puzzles that remain unsolved weeks, months or even years(!) later that some hardy soul will eventually conquer... We tend not to leave comments saying "I'm working on this everyone" because that seems a bit bigheaded and might put others off trying (we always want to encourage others to participate, rather than deter them...). For all I know, others may be mid-solve and further along than me, even - I don't wish to be vain enough to suggest that I would be first to finish (I might not be!). If I can regain my impetus I'll try to see it through... :)

Comment: ^ Turns out I really wasn't the only one working on it! ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I (finally) finished it !

> [image]

Blue squares are 'colored', and green squares are 'not colored'.

This took a few days (I think I started less than a day after the problem was published), and I worked around 6-8 hours (roughly) on this (I'm slow).

Every single pixel here was hand-placed in paint (please don't tell me how many pixels I colored - I don't think I want to know). You can still see the numbers on the picture because I started with the PDF file (converted to png).

I scrolled through all Albrecht Dürer's paintings, and this one seems to be the closest (but I'm not 100% sure about it):

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight,_Death_and_the_Devil

Solving this was really a great (*and long*) experience. And it looks like i'm the first to do it without a computer !

*EDIT : Some comments have been added to the computer answer. According to JMP, the painting I gave in the spoiler is the right one.*

Comment: Oh, fair play :) To be beaten to it like this is something to which I will happily hold up my hands and say well done! I totally feel your pain at the gruelling effort involved (and kudos re Paint - I used Excel personally, with so much fill...). Congrats on being first past the manual solution post! +1

Comment: Congratulations! And there I was about to give up hope that anyone was still working on it. Doing it in paint sounds like great idea, because I noticed that I made several mistakes in Excel, just to save me a few clicks. I hope you enjoyed this kind of puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

Caveat: my answer violates the rules because I solved it using a computer.

I wrote a Python script which reads the input into a list of rows, each of which is treated a list of cells, each of which is, in turn, a two-element tuple containing an integer (the count of filled neighbours for that cell, or 99 if the count is unknown) and a "#" (filled), " " (blank), or "?" (unresolved) character. It then loops, iterating across all cells; for any cell that has unresolved neighbours and has a valid count, if the count of filled neighbours matches the count for this cell then it resolves all unresolved neighbours as blank, or if the count of filled neighbours plus the count of unresolved neighbours matches the count for this cell the it resolves all unresolved neighbours as filled.

Once all cells are resolved it then prints out the grid to a CSV file, which I imported into Excel and manually "search and replaced" the # characters with a black-on-black filled cell - then zoomed right out to be able to see the image.

The answer is:

> [image: Dürer Mosaic]

which is from:

> [Knight, Death and the Devil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight,_Death_and_the_Devil)

(hat tip to @JMP for that).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight,_Death_and_the_Devil

Comment: Got to admit it's disappointing to see the checkmark awarded to an answer which admits it violates the no-computers tag, which was a pretty key request in the original post. Partly this comes from a puzzle purist angle, and partly out of the frustration of wondering why I've spent most of the last 4 days actually bothering to solve this manually as requested (currently c. 75% complete)...

Comment: @Stiv please do still go ahead and post your solution if you complete it manually - I really hope the OP will then award you the checkmark. If you read the comments on the question, I did spend a significant number of hours working on solving it manually until the CSV data in the question was edited and it was rather dispiriting to throw all that away to start again, which was why I ended up writing a script. It's awesome that you're getting there manually! (If you prefer I can even delete my answer - I would hate your hard work to go unrewarded.)

Comment: Please don't delete your answer Vicky on my account - I don't hold anything against you or your answer (should have said that before), just querying the premature checkmark. If anything I'd suggest adding some technical details (What did you code in? Is your script short enough to post in a code block for others to see?). I totally get why the CSV change was gutting for you - the most demoralising moments for me have been the sudden realisation that SOMEWHERE there is a mistake, and it takes hours of rechecking every square for miles around til you finally find it! (5 times so far...) :)