# Quadruped Mosaic

Tags: logical-deduction, visual, grid-deduction, no-computers, minesweeper

This is a visual puzzle (known as "mosaic" or "fill-a-pix") with the same rules as MineSweeper:

- This puzzle has exactly 100 x 100 cells.
- The grid is to be filled with colored and white tessera. Choose whatever color you like for the colored ones.
- The number in each cell indicates how many colored tessera there are in a block of 9 cells around the number - including the numbered cell itself.
- There is absolutely no guessing involved. The color of the tessera must be deduced by the numbers given in the grid.
- If you fill all the cells correctly, you are rewarded with a picture of a happy four-legged friend. The picture was taken from a work of Dutch artist [Adriaen van de Velde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adriaen_van_de_Velde).
- Since the rules are so simple, solving it by a computer algorithm is trivial. **No programming allowed!**

The rules are easy. The size of this puzzle does make it difficult, though. A tiny error can carry forward through many cells until you notice it.

**Hint 1:** It becomes easier to solve if you find two numbers next to each other that have a difference of 3:

[image]

There must be 8 colored tessera and only one white one in the green box. If you put the white one to the right, the red box must have 6 colored tessera in order to add up to 8, but there must be no more than five. That means that the one white tessera of the green box must also be in the red box, adding up to 5 colored ones. Ergo the remaining tessera in the red box but outside of the green box must be white. Also the remaining tessera in the green box but outside of the red box must all be colored because 5 (in the red box) + 3 = 8.

**Hint 2:** You can apply the same principle to blocks of cells that are partially solved:

[image]

There must be 5 colored tessera in the red box and 4 of them are already solved. Ergo the red box must contain one more colored tessera.
There must be 4 colored tessera in the green box and 3 of them are already solved. The green box is also missing one colored tessera, and since it must be inside the red box, the remaining tessera in the green box but outside the red one must be white.

---

You can have a look at [this puzzle I made earlier](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/95411/57005) and get a feeling for it. It seems that the most effective way to solve it on a computer is to convert it to an image and color the cells in MS Paint or a similar program.

[Link to PDF file for printing](http://www.filedropper.com/adriencandervelde2). You'll probably have to print it on 2 pages and glue them together. The cells get too small if printed on one page only. Choose a pencil or sharpie of your liking. Mark the white tessera with a small dot and fill the colored tessera with your pen. Make sure you can still read the numbers in the colored cells.

The puzzle in CSV format to open in Excel or any program of your liking:

```
;4;3;1;;1;2;2;;2;2;;2;1;1;1;;;;0;;0;1;1;1;1;;1;;0;0;1;;2;1;2;;2;2;1;1;0;0;0;;;;;5;6;6;;6;;5;;;1;;;2;3;4;;2;1;;0;0;;;;2;2;;;1;;;0;2;;5;;5;3;;3;3;;;3;;2;;4;5;;3;1;
;;4;1;;1;;;;2;2;;;;;;;1;;;;;2;1;;;;;;;;1;1;2;;;;2;;;1;;0;;0;1;;6;;;9;9;9;9;;6;3;;4;;;;5;;;;;;;2;;;;4;4;2;1;0;0;;4;;7;7;;;3;4;;5;3;;;3;;;6;7;;3;
;;;1;1;0;1;1;2;2;;2;;;1;0;;;0;;1;1;;;1;;;3;2;2;0;2;;2;;2;;1;1;1;;;1;1;1;;;;9;;9;9;;;8;;;3;;6;;;5;5;5;;2;;;2;3;;3;;3;2;2;;;1;4;5;5;4;5;;4;;4;4;;;2;2;2;1;;7;;5;
;6;;;0;0;;;2;1;1;;1;1;0;;1;;3;3;;2;;;1;2;2;;2;2;;2;2;1;;;;0;0;0;0;;1;;;;8;;9;;;9;;;;;4;5;7;8;7;6;6;;5;;2;2;2;;4;5;5;;4;3;;3;;2;;6;;;3;5;5;4;;;;1;3;3;2;;;5;;;
5;6;3;;1;;2;1;3;2;2;;;1;;;;5;;;;3;2;1;1;2;2;3;1;1;1;;2;;2;2;;;0;;;3;3;4;5;;;;9;9;;9;9;9;8;6;5;;8;8;8;8;;;4;3;3;5;;;4;;4;3;2;;2;3;2;2;;5;;4;;5;;4;2;1;0;2;;;1;0;2;3;;;
5;6;3;1;;;;1;;1;1;0;;0;0;;;;;;7;5;2;;1;;;1;;;;;1;1;;;1;0;;1;;;;;7;;;;9;;9;9;;;7;;6;;;;9;;7;7;;5;5;7;6;;5;;;5;3;2;0;1;2;4;;5;;5;4;5;;3;;;;;3;3;0;;;;1;0;
6;6;;;;;;0;1;;;;0;;;4;;9;9;;;6;;2;;1;1;0;0;;;0;;2;3;;;3;3;3;5;7;;7;;8;8;8;7;;8;9;;7;5;6;6;;;8;8;;6;6;;;5;;;;3;;6;5;;;;2;3;;4;4;4;;4;3;2;2;1;;1;3;;;;1;;0;;;
;;4;1;0;;;0;0;0;;;1;;3;6;;;8;6;;6;;3;2;;;2;;;0;1;2;;5;6;;;6;;;6;7;;6;;;7;6;;;7;5;4;2;4;5;8;6;7;7;8;6;5;5;5;;7;;4;3;4;6;;;3;4;4;;5;4;;;3;;;1;;1;1;1;;;5;;4;2;;0;0;
6;;;;;0;;0;0;0;1;;;2;;;9;;;;5;;5;;1;1;3;4;4;3;;;;7;8;;9;9;;8;7;5;5;;4;;;6;5;6;7;;3;1;;3;5;7;5;6;;;7;;4;;5;7;8;;3;3;;;3;4;6;7;;4;;;3;;1;;;0;1;;3;;4;;;7;;;1;;
;;;;4;;;0;0;;1;;2;;;6;6;;;4;;6;;4;;4;6;;;5;4;6;7;;7;8;8;9;8;8;7;5;3;;;4;;;6;;8;;;;0;2;4;5;;;;;;5;;4;6;;9;7;;3;;2;3;5;;;5;;3;;;1;;0;;;4;5;5;5;;7;8;9;8;6;3;1;
6;;8;7;6;5;;;;1;1;2;;;;;6;7;;;;;;;;6;7;8;8;7;6;6;;7;;;8;9;8;7;7;;4;1;2;4;7;6;;5;;6;4;;1;;2;3;3;3;;;6;;;2;;6;;8;;4;2;2;3;6;;8;6;;;;3;1;0;;;;7;8;7;6;5;7;;9;;7;5;3;
6;;;;8;;;6;5;;4;;;;;5;;4;5;5;;;4;;;8;8;;9;7;5;3;4;6;;8;7;;5;;;5;;1;1;;;;5;;4;4;;;2;1;1;;4;;2;2;3;;3;;;5;;;7;4;;1;3;4;7;;5;2;;;;1;;;6;8;;;6;5;5;;9;9;8;;6;;
;8;;;;9;9;9;8;;6;7;7;;;5;;3;4;;3;2;1;4;4;;;;9;;5;;;6;8;;7;;4;4;4;;;1;0;1;2;4;;;3;4;;3;2;;1;;6;;;2;;2;;1;3;;;9;8;;;4;;3;;4;4;;1;0;;;3;6;;8;7;6;;6;7;;9;9;7;7;5;4;
;;8;;;;;;6;7;;6;5;5;4;;;2;3;;2;;1;3;4;;7;;;;;;5;7;7;;;;1;;3;4;;2;1;;1;2;;3;3;4;5;;2;0;1;;5;;4;2;;0;;1;;;;9;8;;;;;;2;2;2;1;;;;;5;;9;8;;;;;8;;;;;6;;;
1;;;;;;7;;;;4;;4;3;;2;4;;;;4;;;5;6;;;9;9;9;;7;6;6;;6;6;;;3;;6;4;3;2;2;2;2;4;5;;;6;6;4;;1;;;4;;2;0;1;3;;4;4;5;7;8;9;8;;5;4;;3;;;0;;1;4;;;;7;;2;;;9;9;;7;6;;3;;
0;;;6;;;7;6;5;5;;;;;6;5;7;;8;7;7;;7;7;8;;;9;;;7;;6;6;;;;7;5;;6;;5;;;5;5;;;6;;5;6;;6;;3;;0;1;1;2;;3;;;4;;3;;7;9;8;6;4;3;;;4;3;;;2;5;8;;9;;;5;;;9;;9;;;5;5;2;
0;0;1;;5;6;;;;;;7;;;8;;9;;;9;9;;;9;9;9;;;;8;;6;6;6;;;8;8;;;5;6;5;5;5;6;6;7;;;;7;7;;;5;3;;;0;;1;;;7;;;4;;;;9;9;7;;;4;6;5;4;;;;;9;9;9;;;;;9;;9;9;7;;;;4;
1;2;;;2;;4;;;6;;;8;;;7;;8;8;8;8;8;8;8;9;9;;;;;;6;6;;7;;8;;8;;;;;;;6;6;7;8;8;;;6;4;;;;;0;0;;;3;6;8;8;8;;;;7;9;9;;;;;5;6;;3;4;;;9;;8;8;8;;9;9;9;9;;;8;8;8;;
1;2;2;2;1;;;2;3;;3;4;;;;7;6;;7;8;;8;;;8;7;8;7;;;7;;;7;;;8;;7;4;3;2;4;5;;;5;;;8;;7;;4;;0;;;0;0;;;4;7;9;;9;;7;;8;;;;8;;3;;;;;;6;9;9;9;;;7;9;;9;;9;;;8;8;8;;
;;3;2;1;1;;;0;;;1;;;6;7;;6;6;;7;7;;;8;;8;7;;7;7;8;7;;;6;8;7;6;3;;2;;5;;6;;3;;;7;;5;;1;0;;0;;1;;2;;7;;9;;9;9;9;9;9;9;;9;;3;;4;4;4;;;9;9;;6;;;;;9;;;;8;;;5;;
;4;3;;;;2;2;0;;1;;;;4;;7;;7;;7;;;;8;;;8;8;;5;;7;8;7;;;5;5;3;3;;6;;;8;6;4;;3;;4;;3;2;0;0;;;;;3;4;7;9;;9;9;;9;9;;9;9;;;;1;3;3;;5;;9;9;;;;;9;;;9;9;9;8;;;5;;
5;;;0;1;3;4;;1;;;1;1;1;2;4;;7;;;7;7;9;9;;9;;;;;6;5;7;7;6;;;;3;3;4;;7;;9;;;4;3;;;4;;;;;1;0;1;;3;2;;;;9;;;;9;;;;8;;7;;4;;4;;6;;9;9;8;8;;;;9;9;;;9;;4;;3;3;
;;;0;1;;4;3;3;;;2;;1;1;;4;;9;8;8;;9;9;9;;;;9;7;5;3;5;;7;;1;2;;4;5;;;;9;;9;6;5;4;5;4;5;5;5;;;;2;3;;3;4;6;8;8;;9;;;;8;8;8;;8;;;7;;7;;9;8;7;7;8;;;;9;;;9;8;;;3;;4;
1;1;0;1;;2;4;3;;2;2;;1;1;;;2;;;9;;;;;;9;9;9;9;;6;3;;;7;;1;;1;;4;;;;8;;9;7;7;7;8;;;;4;2;2;;;2;1;;4;;8;8;9;;9;8;6;;7;8;;;;;;;7;;;8;7;;7;;;9;;9;;8;6;4;;4;;;
;;0;;2;;;;3;2;;1;;1;;0;;;;8;;9;;9;;9;;;;9;;5;5;;8;;2;;;3;5;;6;;;8;9;;;;;;;3;2;;;2;2;2;;4;;6;;8;9;;8;6;6;;;9;;;;;;;8;9;9;7;;6;7;;7;;9;;9;;6;;5;6;;;
1;2;;;4;4;;3;2;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;;2;4;7;8;9;;9;;;;;9;;8;7;;7;8;;;;2;;;;4;3;6;8;;8;;6;4;5;3;;;0;;;;1;1;;4;5;7;;7;5;;3;;;8;;;7;;;6;;;;;7;7;7;;6;;;;9;;8;;7;6;;3;;
2;4;3;4;;3;2;;;1;;0;0;1;1;;0;2;;;7;;9;;;9;;9;;9;;9;7;;;;5;;;;;;4;;7;8;;;4;4;;2;;;1;2;2;2;1;0;;2;;;;5;4;;;2;5;;;;7;;6;6;;;9;8;6;5;;;8;7;8;8;9;9;;9;9;8;6;;2;1;
4;6;;5;;;2;;;2;1;;;3;3;3;;;;;4;;8;;;;9;;9;9;;;;5;6;;;;5;;9;7;6;6;8;7;5;;3;3;2;2;;2;;;2;2;2;2;;;;3;3;2;;1;;;;;6;6;5;6;6;8;;;;;6;;;6;6;6;8;9;9;9;9;;;7;;;;0;
4;;3;2;1;;1;;;2;1;1;2;;5;;;2;;2;;5;;;;;9;9;;9;9;7;5;5;7;;8;7;;8;;7;6;;;7;5;;2;;1;0;;;;;;4;;5;;6;;;;;1;;5;7;;8;6;;6;8;8;9;;9;9;;;;5;5;;;;8;9;;;9;;;;2;;;
;;4;3;2;2;;;4;4;2;2;3;5;7;;5;;1;1;0;;6;;9;;9;9;;8;;7;;;6;7;;;9;9;;;6;5;6;;6;3;1;;2;2;;;0;;2;4;;7;7;6;;2;;;;;6;;9;8;;7;7;8;8;9;;;;;6;;;4;;5;;;9;;;8;;5;;1;;1;
;;3;;3;4;;3;2;4;3;4;4;5;;7;5;5;;2;1;3;;8;9;9;8;;;7;7;;8;6;5;5;7;9;;9;9;;4;;4;7;;3;;;;;;0;1;;;7;7;6;4;;2;;;;1;;5;7;;9;;9;9;9;8;8;;;;5;;7;;5;;;;8;9;;8;7;6;4;;;1;;
;4;4;5;;;4;3;3;4;4;4;;4;4;;4;5;;3;2;2;4;6;;9;;7;6;;5;6;8;7;5;5;7;9;;9;;6;;1;;;5;;3;6;7;;2;;1;2;;5;;5;;2;;1;;0;;;3;6;;;9;9;;;8;;5;5;4;6;7;;;;7;9;9;;8;7;7;6;;;2;0;;0;
1;2;4;;6;5;;2;3;;6;5;;3;3;;4;;4;3;4;3;;;5;7;;;5;4;5;5;;7;7;7;8;8;;7;;5;3;2;3;;5;;;8;;5;;1;2;3;;3;3;3;3;;;3;;0;;0;3;;;;;8;8;8;;5;;;5;6;8;9;8;8;8;9;9;8;8;6;6;;;4;;1;;1;
;3;;5;6;5;5;;;5;6;;4;3;;3;5;4;5;3;4;;2;2;;;;6;5;;;5;7;8;8;;;7;;6;;5;5;5;5;5;5;;;8;7;4;;1;;1;0;0;2;;;;;;3;;0;0;;4;7;;9;;8;;;;5;;;8;;;8;8;9;;;;7;;;6;6;4;2;;1;;
3;;7;;;5;4;4;5;4;5;4;;;6;;;;4;3;3;3;;2;;7;;7;;;;;;7;;6;;;7;;7;7;8;;;;4;6;7;7;5;;1;1;1;1;0;;;3;4;6;8;;5;;;;1;;5;;;7;8;;8;7;;;7;;8;6;;6;;;7;;7;8;8;7;;3;;;;2;
4;7;7;;4;;4;5;6;;3;;;;;6;;;5;;;2;2;4;6;;9;;6;;4;;;;7;5;;;;8;;;;6;6;5;4;4;5;5;;;2;;2;1;;;2;;;7;8;8;;2;0;;;3;;7;;;;;9;;8;8;8;;7;5;3;4;6;8;6;;;;9;8;6;;2;;;;
;;;6;;3;;;;;;1;3;;6;5;6;;;;2;3;2;;6;;9;;7;;;3;5;;8;6;5;5;6;;;;6;;;;3;;4;5;4;4;;;;2;0;;;3;5;7;7;5;;;1;;0;2;4;6;7;8;;9;;;8;9;;9;7;6;3;4;4;7;5;6;;;9;9;6;3;1;2;2;1;
4;7;;5;;;;3;;5;4;;3;5;5;4;;;;;;5;4;6;5;8;;9;;6;4;4;6;8;7;6;5;;;;7;;;;6;5;;;4;;;5;;;5;2;0;1;;;6;7;6;5;3;2;;1;;;;5;;8;;9;;;7;9;;;;;5;4;3;;;4;;8;9;9;7;5;3;;1;;
3;6;6;7;6;7;5;;4;5;;5;5;;5;;4;;6;6;7;6;;;;7;6;7;;;4;4;;;8;7;5;;4;;7;8;8;7;5;;2;;5;;6;6;7;5;3;1;1;3;;;5;;6;;3;;1;1;1;1;;3;5;;7;8;;;5;;;9;8;6;;5;;5;4;5;6;8;9;;8;;4;;;;
3;6;6;;;5;4;;4;6;5;7;6;;5;5;;5;;;8;;5;;5;7;5;6;7;;;6;7;9;;8;5;5;5;;8;7;6;4;3;;;4;;5;;7;6;4;;2;;3;;5;5;;7;;5;;2;1;;;2;;4;;6;;;;;8;9;;;4;;;5;4;5;5;7;;9;;;7;5;3;2;;
3;;;7;5;;;6;;;5;7;7;8;6;;;6;6;6;7;;4;;;8;6;6;7;8;7;7;8;9;;9;;;5;8;8;;;4;;4;5;4;5;6;;8;;;3;3;3;;;;6;7;;5;;4;3;;1;;;5;5;6;;;4;3;;6;8;9;6;;;4;6;7;8;;;;9;;7;;6;5;;3;
;6;4;5;4;3;;;;;4;;5;8;7;6;6;;6;;5;6;4;5;5;;8;8;;;;6;8;9;;9;7;5;;;7;5;3;4;6;;5;4;;7;;;;5;3;3;;;3;6;;;5;6;6;;3;2;;3;4;;;;;;3;;2;;6;;;;;5;;;;6;7;;;8;;5;;4;5;;
;6;;6;;;6;6;7;7;;4;;;6;5;4;;6;5;;;;;4;;;8;;;;5;6;7;;8;6;4;4;6;;6;;;;;2;3;;;8;8;6;3;;;2;4;;8;;;6;;;3;1;1;;2;;;;;5;5;2;1;;2;;8;8;7;6;6;;;;5;6;6;9;;6;;4;;;5;
;;3;;5;;;;;5;;;;6;5;5;;5;6;;5;;3;1;;6;8;;;;7;6;6;;;;6;;;;8;;3;;3;3;2;;;9;9;;;1;;2;4;6;8;9;8;;;7;4;1;;;1;1;;1;2;4;;5;3;;;;5;8;;;;5;;6;;;5;;;9;7;5;;5;;4;
;4;3;5;6;8;8;;5;;;6;4;6;4;5;4;;;4;5;3;;1;3;6;8;;;6;;;7;5;;;;4;4;6;9;7;;3;2;2;2;;7;9;8;5;;;;4;;8;;8;7;;;;3;1;;1;;0;;0;;4;6;;4;;1;2;;;;;6;5;7;7;7;;5;;;;;;7;8;;4;
;;;4;6;7;8;7;5;;5;7;;5;;6;7;6;;4;4;4;4;3;;;8;;;6;8;9;;7;;6;6;5;;7;8;7;;;;3;4;;8;;6;4;;;3;6;8;8;8;8;7;7;8;6;4;2;2;;0;0;0;;2;;5;4;;;1;1;;;9;7;;4;;8;7;;4;;;9;;;9;8;6;3;
4;;5;;;;7;;6;;;6;5;;5;6;6;;;;3;5;;4;;4;;8;7;7;;8;8;7;7;;6;4;4;;;;8;7;5;;4;;;;5;;3;3;4;7;;8;8;8;7;7;;7;5;3;2;;;;;;4;;3;2;1;0;;;;;;8;7;5;6;;;5;;8;;;9;9;;;;2;
5;6;;;5;4;7;;;6;;5;;4;4;6;6;7;4;;;;4;5;2;;6;;9;9;8;;;7;;;5;;;6;5;5;;4;3;2;3;;6;5;;5;5;;5;8;;;8;9;9;9;;6;;2;;1;;;;4;;;;0;;;1;;;;;6;5;;3;;6;6;6;6;;;;;6;3;;1;
5;6;6;;4;5;7;8;7;6;5;;4;;;7;5;6;4;4;;4;4;;;4;;;8;9;;;7;7;6;3;4;4;6;;4;;;;2;1;;3;5;6;;6;5;5;6;8;;;9;9;;;;;;1;;1;;1;4;4;6;;;;;;;1;2;2;;;;2;2;3;5;7;7;6;6;;9;;;2;1;;
4;5;5;4;4;5;6;8;7;7;5;6;6;7;6;7;6;;;5;;;;7;;6;4;6;7;;;;7;;6;;;;8;;3;0;1;1;1;;1;;7;8;8;6;;4;6;8;;;7;7;8;8;5;;;;;1;2;1;;2;4;;3;;;;;2;;;3;;;;;;4;5;;;;;9;;;1;1;;
3;;;6;5;5;5;7;7;7;6;;;;7;;;6;;7;;4;5;;;6;;5;;9;7;;;;;4;4;;8;5;;;2;2;1;;3;;8;;9;6;4;;7;;7;;5;;7;;3;2;1;1;0;0;1;2;;;3;2;3;;3;;1;2;2;2;2;;3;2;1;3;3;;2;;4;;;;;1;1;0;
4;;;7;;4;;5;7;7;7;7;7;6;;;7;;;;7;4;;5;8;7;5;;;8;;5;5;;;5;;;;5;;1;1;;;;4;;;8;;6;5;4;7;;;6;;;5;3;1;1;1;1;;0;;2;;1;;2;;3;;;;3;;;;;3;;;2;2;1;1;;4;;7;;;0;0;;
5;;5;6;7;5;;5;7;7;;7;6;;5;;;6;;5;7;4;4;4;6;;;;4;7;7;;4;6;;;7;8;7;;;2;;2;1;2;4;5;;;9;6;5;;7;8;;;7;;4;1;0;;1;;0;;2;4;4;;;;2;2;2;;;2;3;3;1;3;3;3;0;1;1;;1;;;;;;1;1;;;
5;5;;;7;;4;4;5;;6;;5;;6;;7;5;;5;7;4;4;4;6;6;5;3;;;7;;6;7;;;6;7;;4;1;;3;4;;2;;2;4;;9;6;4;3;;7;;;8;;3;;;;0;;0;;2;;3;;2;;;;3;1;2;3;3;3;;;3;3;;0;0;1;2;2;4;6;7;5;;;0;;
;6;5;5;;;5;4;4;5;6;5;5;4;7;7;8;;;;;;4;;4;;;6;;5;5;6;6;;8;;;5;3;;2;;;6;6;;2;1;2;5;8;;;;;;7;7;8;;;0;;;0;0;;1;;;2;3;2;3;;;3;;;3;3;;1;3;;3;;0;;;3;2;4;;7;5;2;2;2;2;
;7;6;;7;7;5;;3;;;;5;;7;7;7;;6;5;5;;6;;;4;6;;4;5;4;;;9;;7;5;;2;2;3;;6;;;;1;;1;;5;4;4;;;;;6;;5;3;;;1;;;;;1;1;1;3;3;3;2;2;2;2;;;5;3;;;;3;3;;3;;4;3;;6;;;;2;;;
6;;8;;;7;5;;;3;3;4;;;5;;;7;;5;4;;;5;4;3;3;5;3;;3;5;5;;;6;;2;1;2;;6;;;;;1;;;;2;2;4;6;;5;;7;9;;5;4;;3;;0;0;;2;;;;;3;1;;;1;4;;6;4;;3;;4;;4;;4;;;5;;;2;1;3;;;
;;6;;6;8;5;6;;3;;;5;6;5;5;;;4;;6;6;;4;5;4;3;3;3;4;4;;6;8;;;5;3;1;;;;;4;2;1;;1;;;0;;;5;;;6;8;;8;7;7;;4;;0;1;1;2;;;;4;1;;1;2;3;;7;8;7;8;5;6;;6;5;;;2;4;6;;4;1;;4;7;;
;7;6;;;7;6;6;4;4;2;;4;5;5;5;5;6;;6;;5;;;6;5;;3;4;4;;5;;6;7;5;;2;1;;3;5;5;3;1;;2;3;;;;1;3;;6;7;8;9;;9;;;5;;;;2;2;3;;5;;;2;3;2;;4;;7;7;;8;6;;;5;4;1;;;;;5;2;0;3;5;;5;
3;;5;;6;8;7;;4;;;4;;5;;4;6;7;6;6;4;;5;6;7;;;5;6;5;8;7;8;;7;5;;2;1;1;2;5;;3;1;2;4;;4;2;;;2;;;7;;9;9;;7;;3;;1;1;;4;;;4;2;;3;6;;6;;9;;;8;8;7;6;;;4;;;3;;6;;;0;;5;7;5;
;6;;;;7;;;4;5;6;;;;5;5;;8;;6;4;5;;;6;7;8;;6;6;9;8;8;7;7;;;2;2;1;2;4;3;2;1;3;6;;4;1;0;1;2;;;6;8;;8;7;5;3;;;;;5;;;4;;0;;3;;;;;7;8;;;8;8;;7;6;;3;;;5;;5;;0;1;;5;4;
;5;7;7;7;;6;6;4;;6;6;6;;6;5;6;6;5;5;4;6;;8;;;5;4;;6;;9;;;;5;;3;;2;2;4;;2;;;7;7;;2;0;;0;1;2;;7;;7;;3;3;;4;4;5;;7;6;;;;1;2;;;6;7;7;8;;9;;9;;;7;5;;;4;5;6;;4;1;;;3;3;
4;5;;;;7;;8;6;;7;6;6;5;;6;6;;4;;5;;5;7;6;;4;;;5;8;;;8;;;;;2;;;2;2;;3;;;7;;3;;0;;0;1;;6;;;3;;;2;3;;;;;3;1;0;0;0;;2;;;7;;8;8;;;8;8;9;7;;4;5;4;;;5;;1;;0;;;
;5;5;;5;;;8;;7;;5;4;;7;;5;;3;;4;;6;7;;;5;;;5;;;8;;7;7;;5;2;1;;1;;;6;;;;;6;;;0;;;;;;;;;1;1;;;3;;;2;;0;;0;1;;6;8;7;;;8;9;;;;8;;;;4;5;5;6;;;;3;;3;2;
;4;3;3;;;8;8;;;7;;3;;6;7;;;4;5;;6;;6;7;8;8;7;5;4;5;7;;8;8;;;4;;;;0;2;;;7;;7;8;6;5;;;0;;0;1;2;;;1;;;;;0;0;;1;1;;;0;;5;7;8;7;7;7;;;7;7;6;;8;7;7;4;5;;;;2;;;;3;;
3;;4;5;5;7;;7;7;7;7;6;3;4;4;6;;5;4;;5;;5;5;;;8;;;;;8;9;9;;;7;6;;;4;3;;6;6;5;6;;;;;4;2;0;;0;;;;;;1;0;;1;1;;2;2;2;;;1;;7;;;8;7;7;8;;8;;7;8;8;8;;;6;6;;4;;3;;5;4;2;
3;;5;7;;7;7;6;;;;7;;6;;7;7;5;3;4;6;;6;;;;8;7;5;4;5;;;;9;;;;7;;6;5;;7;;;4;6;;6;;;2;;;;;;0;;1;;0;1;1;1;;;;;;;;;8;;9;9;;8;;;8;;8;9;;9;8;5;5;;;3;;2;;;;3;
;6;6;7;8;7;;;5;;;7;7;7;5;;6;6;;;6;8;;;6;5;7;6;4;;;9;9;9;;;9;;9;8;8;;9;;6;4;4;;;6;;3;2;;3;2;2;;;1;0;;;;;1;0;;1;;;5;7;;;;8;;9;7;;;;9;;9;;8;6;4;;6;5;;;1;;6;7;5;
;;;5;;;4;2;3;3;5;;7;7;7;7;6;;4;6;;8;8;7;;7;8;;4;5;;;9;9;9;9;9;;;8;8;;9;9;;;5;;4;3;1;;2;4;6;;;4;;1;0;;;;;;;;0;;4;;8;9;9;;8;;9;7;;;;8;8;8;;7;;5;5;5;3;;0;;4;7;;5;
4;;5;5;4;;3;;2;2;3;4;6;7;;6;;8;;6;;7;;;7;8;8;;4;4;5;;;9;;9;9;9;;9;;8;8;9;9;7;;6;;3;;1;;;8;6;5;4;;;1;;1;;;;2;3;1;4;5;7;;8;9;;8;;;7;;;8;;8;;7;6;;;4;4;3;2;;1;3;5;7;;
3;4;3;;2;2;;2;;1;3;4;5;;6;;;6;6;5;4;4;;7;;;7;7;;4;5;7;9;9;;;;;;;;8;;7;7;;;7;;;;;4;6;6;4;;2;;;1;;1;2;;4;3;;;5;5;;;;;8;;;;8;;;7;5;6;;5;5;5;7;;5;4;3;;;1;;;;
;;2;;1;1;;1;2;3;5;6;5;5;4;4;;5;5;;;;3;4;5;;6;;6;5;5;;;9;9;9;;9;9;9;8;8;;6;6;7;;;5;3;;1;3;4;3;1;;;0;0;2;3;3;;;3;2;;4;6;;5;5;;7;6;;6;7;;;7;;5;;;5;;6;;6;;;4;2;0;;0;;2;
;2;;;0;;;0;;4;6;;5;;;2;;;;;;;;2;;;;6;;6;;6;9;;;9;9;;;9;;;;;4;6;;6;4;3;;2;2;;;0;0;;;2;3;;;3;1;1;;3;5;6;;;6;7;;;;6;7;7;6;;;5;;2;;5;;9;8;6;4;2;;;;;1;1;
2;;1;;1;0;0;0;1;;;5;;3;1;0;;;2;1;0;0;0;1;2;3;4;5;;;6;6;;9;9;;9;9;;9;9;;6;;;6;;4;;3;;3;;0;;0;0;0;1;2;4;;5;;;0;;3;;;3;4;5;;6;;5;;;6;;;6;5;4;;;6;;9;;6;4;;;;0;0;0;;
2;2;;1;;1;1;2;;2;1;;2;2;;;;1;;2;;;0;;2;2;2;3;;4;;6;;9;;9;;9;;8;;;6;5;6;;6;3;;;4;3;;;;;;0;;2;;;;;0;0;2;;6;;4;;4;5;;6;;6;7;7;4;;3;3;;1;4;;;9;8;6;3;;;;0;0;;1;
1;2;;2;1;2;2;3;;;;;;0;0;;1;2;2;2;;;1;4;3;;;;;;;6;9;9;;9;9;;8;;;9;8;8;8;;4;;1;1;;1;;0;;0;;0;;;5;5;4;;0;;4;6;7;;4;4;;;2;;4;5;7;;;;;;2;3;6;;9;;9;7;;;0;1;2;;4;3;
2;;3;3;;4;4;4;3;2;1;;;;0;;1;;;2;2;2;2;;4;;1;0;1;;4;;;9;;;9;9;;6;6;8;8;;8;;;1;2;3;3;3;2;;;1;;0;;3;;3;;1;2;;;7;;9;7;;3;2;1;1;2;3;5;6;6;;1;1;3;;;9;;;9;;3;1;;;3;;;5;
3;;;;3;;;;2;;2;;1;;2;;3;2;;;2;;3;3;4;3;2;1;;;;6;9;9;;9;9;;8;6;;5;6;;;5;3;;;6;;6;4;2;;1;2;;;5;5;;;3;;6;6;;7;8;7;;;3;3;2;;1;3;4;5;4;;4;6;8;9;9;;8;;6;3;2;;2;;;9;;
;7;6;;4;;4;;;;5;5;;4;4;5;5;3;2;;2;;3;;6;4;4;2;2;1;;;;;9;;9;9;;;;2;3;;4;;;;7;;9;;5;;2;;5;5;5;4;;2;4;;7;7;;;;;7;;6;;;;;0;1;3;4;;;7;;;8;9;7;6;;;;2;;2;4;;;;
5;;;6;5;5;4;4;3;;6;6;5;6;7;;;;3;0;;2;;4;5;;4;;;;3;;;9;9;;;9;;7;5;;2;;4;6;;;;9;8;6;;2;;4;5;;;5;4;5;6;6;;6;5;;6;;;;;;6;;2;;2;2;3;;;;7;8;;8;6;;2;2;;2;;;5;;;2;
5;;6;6;;;6;;5;5;;6;7;;8;8;;;;2;;1;;6;6;6;;4;2;1;;;9;9;9;;9;;9;8;;;2;1;;7;9;;9;;;;;4;6;6;;5;5;6;;;8;;4;;;7;;6;5;;6;8;;;1;;3;3;4;7;;7;;8;7;;4;2;1;;;;2;;;6;4;;
;6;;6;;9;;5;5;5;7;6;;7;;;;6;;4;;;5;6;5;;5;;;4;;8;9;;;;;7;;;;4;;3;6;7;7;;8;;;;5;5;;4;2;3;;8;;;;5;;4;;8;;7;;;;;;4;;;;4;5;7;6;;7;;7;;;;;;0;;2;3;5;;;2;
;5;;;7;7;;6;;6;7;;7;;;9;;;;;7;;;7;;;;6;;;;9;9;9;9;8;7;7;8;8;7;5;;;7;7;;6;7;7;;;5;;3;;;;;7;5;;3;;3;5;;7;;;6;;5;;5;6;4;;3;6;;7;;;;;6;3;0;0;;;;0;2;;6;7;6;;
3;;5;6;6;5;5;6;7;8;;9;6;;;;8;6;7;7;;8;7;7;6;;5;5;6;8;;9;;9;;8;;;8;8;;6;7;;;;7;6;7;;;;5;;1;;3;5;;5;3;;;2;2;;7;7;7;6;7;;5;4;;6;6;;;7;8;;7;7;9;8;5;2;;;;0;;0;2;4;;;6;;
;4;5;;6;3;;6;;;6;7;5;4;5;6;;7;;;;7;;;;;5;;7;;9;9;9;;9;;9;;;9;;9;;9;;;;;8;7;;;6;;3;3;5;6;;2;;3;2;2;;;6;;;6;;;6;;6;;;7;;9;9;;;8;;8;6;4;2;;;;;1;4;;9;7;5;;
2;;6;7;6;;4;;7;;6;;;;;;7;7;7;;6;;;;;4;4;5;;9;9;;9;;;9;9;;;;8;8;8;;7;;;9;;9;9;;9;;;6;;5;;;1;3;;2;0;1;;;;7;;7;;5;;5;;;9;8;8;;;9;;8;7;5;;2;2;3;3;2;;;9;;;1;
;2;5;6;6;4;3;;;;;;;5;;8;7;7;6;6;;6;7;;;;;7;9;9;;9;9;;9;;;9;9;;;6;5;;6;8;9;9;;;;;9;9;;;;4;1;;0;;;1;0;0;1;2;3;5;;8;;;6;6;8;9;;7;;8;9;9;;9;;6;3;2;2;3;4;;6;7;;;;0;
1;2;3;5;4;3;2;3;5;4;6;3;5;4;;7;;5;;5;;6;7;;3;;4;;;;;9;9;;9;;;;9;8;;;4;;5;7;8;;6;;5;7;;9;9;;;3;1;;1;;0;0;0;;;0;;3;;;5;5;6;7;9;8;;6;;8;;;9;9;7;;;1;0;2;;6;6;;5;;;;
;1;;;;1;;2;4;;4;3;4;4;;;4;;;5;;5;7;8;;;5;;;8;;9;;9;;;;;;7;4;;;7;;7;;;5;3;;6;8;;8;;4;;1;1;2;1;;;;1;;;1;2;;4;;;6;7;7;6;6;;7;8;8;8;8;8;;;3;2;;2;4;;;4;;1;0;0;
;1;0;0;0;;3;4;;;;4;4;5;4;4;4;;;4;5;5;6;7;7;8;;7;6;;7;8;9;8;;7;;7;6;4;3;5;;;7;;7;8;6;3;3;;;;;6;3;2;;3;;2;;;1;;4;4;;1;1;;;2;4;5;;3;4;;5;5;5;;6;7;;7;5;3;1;2;;3;2;1;0;0;0;0;
0;;0;0;0;0;;;3;3;;;6;8;;5;;4;;3;3;4;;;8;7;7;6;6;6;6;;;;;4;6;5;5;3;4;;;8;6;6;;8;6;4;5;7;;9;7;;1;;;4;4;4;;;2;;4;4;2;1;;1;1;1;;;;1;2;2;;2;;2;3;4;5;;;;2;1;;0;;;;;;;
;;;1;1;1;;2;;4;;;6;6;4;4;;;2;3;3;;6;6;;;8;;7;6;7;;;;5;2;;;4;;7;8;;;6;5;;5;;;6;;;;;4;;3;5;5;4;4;4;4;3;;;3;;0;0;;;0;0;;;;;0;;0;0;0;;;4;;3;2;;0;;;;2;2;1;;0;
0;0;;1;1;;0;;0;;;6;;;3;;;;4;5;4;;;6;6;;;5;6;7;8;7;7;;;4;;3;5;;;;;6;;;6;;;4;;9;9;;7;;3;4;4;5;5;5;;3;;2;;;0;1;1;1;1;1;;0;;0;;;1;;0;0;1;1;;0;;;2;1;;;1;3;3;2;1;;
2;2;;1;;;0;0;0;1;2;;2;1;;2;;6;6;7;6;6;;6;6;6;6;;;;8;;9;8;8;7;;;5;8;;;;6;7;;7;;;;8;;;8;7;;;;6;;;3;;3;2;1;;1;;2;;1;;;1;0;0;0;;;;;0;;;;2;1;;3;3;;;0;1;3;4;3;;2;
;;2;0;0;;0;;;;0;1;;1;;;;7;7;;;;7;7;7;;;8;6;7;7;;9;;9;9;;;;7;8;;;;8;9;;8;8;8;9;;8;6;5;4;5;;5;;;;;2;;0;;1;3;;4;;;1;2;;;1;2;;3;2;0;;;;1;1;;;4;2;0;0;0;2;3;4;5;4;
;6;;1;;1;1;;;;;;;0;0;;5;;;;;;7;7;7;6;6;;;7;;9;9;;;9;8;7;;;8;7;8;;;9;;;9;;9;;;5;4;3;;5;6;5;4;3;;;1;0;;1;;;;2;0;0;;;2;3;3;5;;3;;;;2;2;;2;;;2;0;0;0;1;2;4;6;5;
;6;4;2;;1;;;;0;0;0;;;;1;3;;3;1;2;4;;;5;;;;;5;6;;9;;;;;;8;;8;;;9;9;;7;;;8;8;7;;3;2;;3;3;;;;3;2;;0;;;;2;4;3;;;;;3;3;4;;;6;4;2;0;1;;1;;1;;3;3;;1;;0;;2;;5;
5;;6;5;4;2;1;1;2;1;;0;;;0;;;1;;0;0;;;4;3;3;;2;3;4;;7;;8;;;9;;9;9;;9;;8;;5;;;5;;;4;3;3;3;;2;;2;3;2;;0;0;;;0;;0;;1;1;0;;;4;4;4;5;5;;5;3;1;;;1;1;1;3;3;;;2;;1;2;3;;3;
;5;6;6;;3;1;;1;1;1;;0;;0;;0;;0;0;;;1;;1;2;1;;;;4;5;;;5;;6;;6;6;;;;;4;;;1;;2;;1;0;1;1;;0;1;1;;;0;;;0;;0;0;1;1;1;;;;;;5;4;4;;;5;2;;0;;;;;;;4;3;;;3;;;;2;
1;;4;;;;;0;1;1;1;;;;;;;;0;;;0;0;;1;;0;0;1;;;;2;2;2;;;3;3;;3;3;;2;;;1;;1;0;0;;0;1;1;;0;1;;1;0;;;;;0;0;;1;;1;1;;;3;;;;2;3;2;3;1;;0;;0;;;1;1;;2;2;1;3;4;5;;1;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I chose to solve this using Excel, which took me about 9-10 hours, I think - I suspect it would have been much quicker to infill a PDF image using MS Paint (or equivalent), or possibly even do it manually by printing it off! Still, I believe (unless I have made a silly mistake somewhere - and believe me, it's easy to do...) that the final solved mosaic should give the following image:

> [image: Completed mosaic]

The work by Adriaen van de Velde that this image has been extracted from is:

> [*Cows and sheep. Plate 2: A pied bull and three sheep.*](https://collections.tepapa.govt.nz/object/37831)

...which means that the quadruped depicted within it is:

> a **BULL**!

Comment: Wow, that was quick! Congratulations. Did you like it? I was planning on making more of these types of puzzles if people liked them (it's quite hard to find suitable pictures)

Comment: @Elmy I've been doing a lot of more regular-sized minesweepers recently and getting disappointed by poor quality ones (in one book of puzzles I found, 4 of the puzzles contained ALL mines with no safe spaces!!), so this came along at the perfect time for me to tackle a proper challenge :) I only had a couple of long backtracks, and the last section I completed (middle left-hand edge) was the trickiest by far - the last 250 or so spaces took me 2 hours just by themselves!

Comment: @Elmy I would say there's definitely potential for more of these, but you'd want to spread them out rather than drop them all too soon after another, to avoid puzzle type fatigue. If you do do any more, I will leave them to others to have a go at solving - they're very labour-intensive to solve, so I should probably spread my time around some other endeavours now that I've managed to solve one of these! Thanks for the puzzle :)